# Count int occurrences with Java8

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a better way to count int occurrences with Java8

```
int[] monthCounter = new int[12];
persons.stream().forEach(person -> monthCounter[person.getBirthday().getMonthValue() - 1]++);
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Try:

```
 Map<Integer, Long> counters = persons.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getBirthday().getMonthValue(), 
         Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: It is a really good idea, nevertheless is there a way to have the final count into an array instead of a Map?

Comment: Arrays.setAll(array, counters::get);

Comment: what is this? counters::get

Comment: It is a bound method reference, equivalent to the lambda `i -> counters.get(i)`

Comment: @BrianGoetz isn't counters::get a unBounded method reference?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller "Bound" means that the receiver of the method call is bound at lambda capture time.

Answer (score 6):

There's a few variations this could take.

You can use `Collectors.summingInt()` to use `Integer` instead of the `Long` in the count.

If you wanted to skip the primitive `int` array, you could store the counts directly to a `List` in one iteration.

**Count the birth months as Integers**

```
Map<Integer, Integer> monthsToCounts = 
        people.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getBirthday().getMonthValue(), 
                Collectors.summingInt(a -> 1)));
```

**Store the birth months in a 0-based array**

```
int[] monthCounter = new int[12];
people.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getBirthday().getMonthValue(), 
                        Collectors.summingInt(a -> 1)))
                        .forEach((month, count) -> monthCounter[month-1]=count);
```

**Skip the array and directly store the values to a list**

```
List<Integer> counts = people.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getBirthday().getMonthValue(), 
        Collectors.summingInt(a -> 1)))
        .values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (formerly [GS Collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections)), you can make use of a data structure called `Bag` that can hold the number of occurrences of each element.

Using `IntBag`, the following will work:

```
MutableList<Person> personsEC = ListAdapter.adapt(persons);
IntBag intBag = personsEC.collectInt(person -> person.getBirthDay().getMonthValue()).toBag();

intBag.forEachWithOccurrences((month, count) -> System.out.println("Count of month:" + month + " is " + count));
```

If you want to make use of an array to keep track of the count, you can combine with the `Arrays.setAll()` approach [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) pointed out in another answer.

```
int[] monthCounter  = new int[12];
MutableList<Person> personsEC = ListAdapter.adapt(persons);
IntBag bag = personsEC.collectInt(person -> person.getBirthDay().getMonthValue()).toBag();
Arrays.setAll(monthCounter, bag::occurrencesOf);
System.out.println(IntLists.immutable.with(monthCounter));
```

This code will also work with Java 5 – 7 if you use anonymous inner classes instead of lambdas.

**Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections**

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to get Integer to Integer map, you can do the following.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> counters = persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        p -> p.getBirthday().getMonthValue(),
        Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered. Small Suggestion from my side inorder to eliminate **null** pointer exception
ie  From the stream null will throw **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**, **java.lang.NullPointerException**

```
Map<Integer, Long> birthdayCount = persons.stream()
                                    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filter out null object
                                    .filter(p->Objects.nonNull(p.getBirthday())) // filter out null birthdays
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> 
                                                 p.getBirthday().getMonthValue(), 
                                                 Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score -5):

```
int size = persons.stream().count()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: `count()` returns long you need to cast to int, so this doesn't compile. It wouyld be `int size = (int) persons.stream().count()`