# How to get the frequency of numbers in a list

Tags: java, collections

I have a list of five numbers (a hand of cards). I'd like to get the frequency of each number in the list, and put that in a map, or something similar.

I know it's easy to implement this yourself. But I was curious, is there a way to do so in the Collections framework?

---

(To be clear, not the frequency of any particular number, but the frequency of every number, in the list.)

Comment: For a Java 8 solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/23925315/1441122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Guava `HashMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html), it has the counting built right into it:

```
HashMultiset<String> set = HashMultiset.create(yourList);
int x = set.count("abc");
```

You can also iterate and get the count over all elements:

```
for(Multiset.Entry<String> entry : set.entrySet()) { 
    System.out.println(entry.getElement() + " -> " + entry.getCount());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in the (Collections)[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html] class called [frequency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object))

It is used as follows:

```
int occurrences = Collections.cards(animals, "1");
```

I'm pretty sure this is JDK 1.6 updwards

Comment: Yeah, I know about the frequency method. But it's not what I want. Because you have to give a specified element. I'd like it to return me a map of frequencies for all values.

Comment: In which case, no real method that I am aware of other than looping through the list and adding to a map and increasing one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(1);
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(list);
    for(Integer tmp:set)
    {       
    System.out.println("frequency of element "+ tmp + " : " + Collections.frequency(list, tmp));
    }
```