# How to count occurrencies of an entity in a list with repetitions?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of 5-digit combinations (possibly with repetitions: doubles, triples, etc). I need to count how often every combination appears in that list. Actually, a combination is a unique BitSet with respective bits set (if combination contains digit 5 then 5th bit is set, etc.)

Given list

```
12345
34578
12345
98710
12345
```

I shall get

```
12345 -> 3
34578 -> 1
98710 -> 1
```

Is there anything ready to solve this task? Like I add 12345 string to this data structure three times and then I query it for 12345 (respective Bitset object) and it returns 3 as number of occurrencies. I thought of Apache Commons  Frequency class, but it does not help.

Comment: Convert the list into a set and then iterate over the set and count against the list

Comment: `Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Streams can help, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925315/count-int-occurrences-with-java8

Comment: A frequency count sounds like what you need. Can you explain `it does not help`?

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a ready-to-use data structure which *stores* elements with counts, then **[Guava's `Multiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html)** does exactly that.

If you just need to convert a list to a map of counts, please read on.

You can convert a list to a map of counts in a single statement using Java 8 Streams API:

```
final var list = List.of("12345", "34578", "12345", "98710", "12345");

final var counts = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(), // Map keys are list elements
        value -> 1, // Map values are counts, a single item counts "1"
        (count1, count2) -> count1 + count2 // On duplicate keys, counts are added
    ));
```

Under the hood, this solution uses a hash map (elements to counts) as a data structure.

You may also use the `groupingBy` collector, as [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey) kindly suggested:

```
final var list = List.of("12345", "34578", "12345", "98710", "12345");

final var counts = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(), // Group the elements by equality relation
        Collectors.counting() // Map values are counts of elements in the equality groups
    ));
```

---

Sometimes (while learning) it's beneficial to implement everything "by hand" to understand the algorithms. So here a version *without Java 8 goodies* like streams, collectors and new map methods like [`Map.compute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
final List<Stream> list = List.of("12345", "34578", "12345", "98710", "12345"); // Use ArrayList if you're below Java 9

final Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
for (final String item : list) {
    // Note: I'm deliberately NOT using Map.compute() here
    // to demonstrate how to do everything "manually"
    Integer count = counts.get(item);
    if (count == null) {
        count = 0;
    }
    counts.put(item, count + 1);
}
```

Comment: or `Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p, Collectors.counting());`

Comment: "I'm deliberately NOT using Map.compute()" `Map.merge` would be an easier alternative than `Map.compute` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list are strings (if not you might need a "comparator"). Loop over the entire list adding the elements to a `HashMap` and a counter of themselves; but right before doing that, check if the element in question exists, updating the counter accordingly.

Eventually, Java streams can help too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plain [Collections.frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) method that does exactly that.

```java
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.Collections.frequency;

List list = List.of("12345", "34578", "12345", "98710", "12345");
System.out.println( frequency(list, "12345") );
```