# Reworking method with stream usage

Tags: java, java-stream

I wrote this method to calculating number of data usage. It receives LinkedList (historyDate)with data, then i add it to Set for avoiding duplicates and calculating key-value(data - count) in Map

```
 public Map<String, Integer> countCodingsByDate() {
    Set<String> dateCount = new HashSet<>(codingHistory.historyDate);
         Map<String, Integer> dateOccurence = new HashMap<>();
         for (String s : dateCount) {
             int count = 0;
             for (String a : codingHistory.historyDate) {
                 if (s.equals(a)) {
                     count++;
                 }
             }
             dateOccurence.put(s, count);
         }
         return dateOccurence;
     }
```

Output:

```
{28-11-2019=5, 29-11-2019=3}
```

I have a qustion - in what way and how can i rework it with stream? Thank you for an answer

Comment: I don't really understand your code. You are basically producing a map where every value (count) is 1.

Comment: Indeed, the question is lacking your detailed explanation of the problem and what problems you may be having with your own attempt at a solution

Comment: added explanation

Comment: Related, but probably not duplicates: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441088/group-by-counting-in-java-8-stream-api), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925315/count-int-occurrences-with-java8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can work with a `Map<String, Long>` then you can use this:

```
public Map<String, Long> countCodingsByDate() {
    return codingHistory.historyDate.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(),
            Collectors.counting()
        ));
}
```

Note: This is the normal way to find out the occurances of a `Collection`. For similar questions, see: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441088/group-by-counting-in-java-8-stream-api), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925315/count-int-occurrences-with-java8)

Comment: It won't compile. The correct return type is `Map<String, Long>`.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, small copy paste error, I've corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
Map<String, Integer> result = codingHistory.historyDate.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(date -> date, date -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `Collectors.groupingBy` for use case like yours.

```
Map<String, Long> groupedByDate = codingHistory.historyDate.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```